# steps to deploy the BIRT reports in jboss AS7

Tags: jboss7.x, birt

for reports= BIRT
server =JBOSS AS 7.1.1
front end =Richfaces

i have created some reports using BIRT.But when i am calling the reports through my webpage it is showing error.

how to deploy the reports in jboss and how to call the reports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Eclipse's BIRT Viewer Setup documentation [here](http://eclipse.org/birt/documentation/integrating/viewer-setup.php).

From the 'Deploying to JBoss' section of the referenced link:

> - Download the zip file with the BIRT report engine runtime. The file is named birt-runtime-version#.zip.
> - Unzip the file in a staging area.
> - Look under the birt-runtime- directory and locate the "WebViewerExample" directory.
> - Copy the "WebViewerExample" directory to your JBoss installation, under the deploy directory for your configuration. (eg) C:\dev\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments.
> - Rename the WebViewerExample directory to birt.war, so it will deploy in place.
> - Start up JBoss and enter the URL to BIRT (ie http://localhost:8080/birt) and run the test report.

Comment: i have done all the above steps you have provided but i am getting  these error                                                                                            HTTP Status 404 - /birt

type Status report

message /birt

description The requested resource (/birt) is not available.
JBoss Web/7.0.10.Final

Comment: Does the JBoss server.log indicate that the birt.war was deployed?  The log should say - Deployed "birt.war".